# Strip double quotes from single quotes in string

Tags: python, quote

```
['00', '11"', 'aa', 'bb', "cc'"]
```

This is in Python. I want to strip off the double quotes so that my output becomes

```
['00', '11', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc']
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Is your data in the form of a string?

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you've to use the `str.strip()` function two times here.
First to remove the `"` and then  `'`.

```
In [1]: lis=['00', '11"', 'aa', 'bb', "cc'"] 

In [2]: [x.strip('"').strip("'") for x in lis]
Out[2]: ['00', '11', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc']
```

or as suggested by @DSM we don't require 2 `strip()` calls:

```
In [14]: [x.strip("'" '"') for x in lis]
Out[14]: ['00', '11', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc']
```

because, neighboring string literal are automatically combined :

```
In [15]: "'" '"'
Out[15]: '\'"'

In [16]: "a"'b'"c"'d'
Out[16]: 'abcd'
```

Another alternative can be `regex`:

```
In [6]: [re.search(r'\w+',x).group() for x in lis]
Out[6]: ['00', '11', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc']
```

Comment: You can do it in one `strip`: `[x.strip("'" '"') for x in lis]`.  (Here I've taken advantage of the fact that neighbouring string literals are combined; `'"\''` would work too, but I have trouble reading escaped strings.)

Comment: @DSM I almost forgot about this concept, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: I would use `.replace` probably, without a reason to specifically remove the quotes only from the ends.

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.6 and newer Python 2.x versions:

```
line = ['00', '11"', 'aa', 'bb', "cc'"] 
line = [x.translate(None,'\'\"') for x in line]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of regular expressions. Have a look at this site for more information.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/python.html

Regular expressions are the code version of Find and Replace. What you are looking for is to use a regular expression such as r'[\'\"]' and replace it with an empty string. While Python is not my biggest strength, that should give you a push in the right direction.